# Strange routing behaviour when using NetworkManager with strongswan for IKE from docker

Tags: docker, strongswan, networkmanager

I have a situation that is causing me a problem:
I historically had a VPN server which provided the L2TP connection, I upgraded it to IKEv2.
This is going well, multi-platform clients access it correctly, no problems.
I added a route in the vpn-up & vpn-down dispatcher scripts this:
ip route add to default dev tun0 proto static scope link metric 50

The problem arises in the case where one of the service's clients uses Docker from an Unbuntu machine which uses Strongswan with NetworkManager, in this case the containers exhibit strange behavior as follows:

If I connect to a container of this machine, I launch a google.fr traceroute I notice that the container does not take into account the presence of the tunnel, which is not the case if I connect in L2TP where I see clearly transit with the right gateway.
On the other hand, if I reboot the machine, connect to my IKE service, disconnect then connect to L2TP, disconnect then reconnect to IKE, then the traceroute takes me through the tunnel correctly.

I did different tests with the id 220 routing table, without success, I tried in view of the description above to reproduce the routing elements in the case where it works to set it up for the first connection and that does not gives nothing.

I compared the iptables rules in the case where it works and where it doesn't and they are identical.
Also I compared the parameters that we observe via sysctl -a I do not see any notable elements, sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward and indeed equal to 1.

I'm a bit at the end of the race, if anyone has an idea to suggest to me I'm interested!

I got that on Ubuntu 18, Ubuntu 22, Debian 11 & 12
On my test machine I have:

- network-manager    1.36.6-0ubuntu2
- network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu    1.36.6-0ubuntu2
- network-manager-l2tp    1.20.8-1~ubuntu22.04.1~ppa1.1
- network-manager-l2tp-gnome    1.20.8-1~ubuntu22.04.1~ppa1.1
- network-manager-openvpn    1.8.18-1
- network-manager-openvpn-gnome    1.8.18-1
- network-manager-pptp    1.2.10-1
- network-manager-pptp-gnome    1.2.10-1
- network-manager-strongswan    1.5.2-1
- networkd-manager-dispatcher    2.1-2ubuntu0.22.04.2

Comment: Ok after trying to use a custom routing table other than 220 I finally have the good routing!